# Sorting files on extension (kind) and then date in Finder? (Mojave)

Tags: macos, finder, folders, mojave, sort

When viewing a folder in Finder, by clicking the different column headings you can select how you want the folder contents sorted: by name, kind (extension), modified date, et cetera.

What I would like is to see is all files of a certain kind grouped together, and then sorted on date. For example, all .jpg files sorted on date, then all .txt files sorted on date, and so on.

So something like a 'combined' sorting criterium, where kind or filetype takes higher precedence, and then (for files with the same extension) date, and perhaps even more criteria.

Is this possible in Finder? Can I perhaps even define or customize my own 'sorting rules' ?

In case it matters, I'm using macOS 10.14 Mojave.

Comment: I'm not running macOS Mojave yet however, in macOS High Sierra when I want to sort on two criteria in Finder, when in List View select the column, e.g. Kind, then press Command-J, then select the second criteria in the Arrange By: list box. You also can just select the folder and press Command-J and select the criteria in both the Arrange By: and Sort By: list boxes.

Comment: @user3439894 Awesome, that worked like a charm (it's called Group By: and Sort By: in Mojave, but appears to be the same) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

1. Click the Group button, then choose an option, e.g. kind.
2. Hold the <kbd>Option</kbd>  key and click the Group button again, now you can choose the criteria to sort by.

Tested on macOS Ventura.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: Worked perfectly. Could you please share some documentation about this? How did you find out?